# css background-image not showing at all

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

I'm having troubles showing a background-image using css instead of an  tag in HTML code, and I can't see where is the mistake. I went through multiple threads, where people were suggesting using 'background' instead of 'background-image' or putting 'display:block;' to the css, putting in some height and width to the `<p>` I'm trying to get the background image to etc.
Nothing really helped me. If i put the 'background-color' selector, the `<p>` reacts, but i just can't get the background-image visible.
I tried to get rid of the js code as well to see whether there's some collision, and also tried to get rid of the css completely and put the background image directly in the html, havent showed up as well.
I'm certain I have the relative path written correctly.

```js
    var myImage = document.querySelector('img');
    
    myImage.onclick = function() {
      var mySrc = myImage.getAttribute('src')
      if(mySrc === 'images/gang.jpg') {
        myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/gang2.jpg');
      } else {
        myImage.setAttribute ('src','images/gang.jpg');
      }
    }
    
    var myButton = document.querySelector('button');
    var myHeading = document.querySelector('h1');
    
    function setUserName() {
      var myName = prompt('Please enter your name.');
      localStorage.setItem('name', myName);
      myHeading.textContent = 'Tortoises are cool as fuck, ' + myName;
    }
    
    if(!localStorage.getItem('name')) {
      setUserName();
    } else {
      var storedName = localStorage.getItem('name');
      myHeading.textContent = 'Tortoises are cool as fuck, ' + storedName;
    }
    
    myButton.onclick = function() {
      setUserName();
    }
```

```css
    html {
      font-size: 20px;
      font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
      background-color: #6b4e15;
      color: #332e27;
    }
    
    body {
      width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #eabe69;
      padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
      border: 5px solid black;
    }
    
    img {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 100%
    }
    
    h1 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 20px 0;
      color: #6b4e15;
      text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px black;
      font-size: 60px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    p, li {
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 1.5;
      letter-spacing: 0px;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #332e27;
      border: 1px solid #332e27;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding-left: 7px;
      padding-right: 7px;
      margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }
    
    a:hover {
      color: #eabe69;
      background-color: #332e27;
      border: 1px solid #332e27;
      border-radius: 5px;
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
    }
    
    address {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #squirtel {
      background-image: url('./images/pokemon.png');
      width: 1000;
      height: 1000;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
      <meta charset='utf-8'>
      <title> Tortoise is cool </title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles/style.css' type='text/css'>
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial' rel="stylesheet">
      <meta name='author' content='Jan Jansa'>
      <meta name='description' content='The best page about tortoises'>
      <meta property='og:image' content='images/gang.jpg'>
      <meta property='og:description' content='Ahoj tohle je zelvi stranka o zelvach a je hodne v pohode'>
      <meta property='og:title' content='Hey! Tortoise is cool!'>
      <meta property='og:type' content='website'>
      <meta property='og:site_name' content='Hey! Tortoises are cool!'>
      <meta property='og:url' content='https://jankko7.github.io/'>
      <link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1> Tortoise is cool! </h1>
      <img src='images/gang.jpg' alt='Four little tortoises on white stone lying with their bellies up'>
      <p> <a href='#changeuser'> Tortoises are: </a></p>
      <ul>
        <li> Cool </li>
        <li> Osinka </li>
        <li> Ferda </li>
      </ul>
      <p id='squirtel'> <a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginated_tortoise' target='_blank'>
        The marginated tortoise (Testudo marginata) </a>
        is a species of tortoise found in Greece, Italy and the Balkans in southern
        Europe. It is the largest European tortoise, reaching a weight of up to 5 kg (11 lb) and
        a length of 35 <abbr title='centimeters'>cm</abbr> (14 <abbr title='inches'>in</abbr>). Its shell is oblong and has a notable thickness
        around the middle of the body. The posterior end of the shell has
        a saw-like formation, flanged outward <strong>like a bell</strong>. The carapaces of adult
        specimens are almost completely black, with yellow highlights. The front
        sides of the limbs are covered with large scales. The tail is notable for
        a lengthwise marking and for an undivided carapace over the tail.
        The marginated tortoise is herbivorous, and hibernates for the winter.
        The Marginated Tortoise is recorded for the first time from Turkey, from
        the delta of the Küçük Menderes River which is less than 250 <abbr title='kilometers'>km</abbr> away from
        the closest known area in Greece.
      </p>
      <h2> Tortoise X Turtle X Blastoise </h2>
      <dl>
        <dt> <a href='images/tortoise.jpg'>Tortoise</a></dt>
        <dd> a reptile with shield living on <strong>a dry land</strong>. </dd>
        <dt> <a href='images/turtle.jpg'>Turtle</a></dt>
        <dd> a reptile with shield living in <strong> a sea </strong> or <strong> an ocean </strong>.</dd>
        <dt> <a href='images/blastoise.png'>Blastoise</a></dt>
        <dd> a reptile with a shield and ability to <strong> hydro blast </strong> you to the flippin sky. </dd>
      </dl>
      <button id='changeuser'> Change User </button>
      <h2> Contact me </h2>
      <p> You can <a href='mailto:jan.jansa95@gmail.com?cc=jan.jansa@icloud.com&subject=Let%20me%20ask%20you%20bout%20turtles%20bro!&body=Hi%20friend%20let%20me%20ask%20you%20this%2C%0B%0B'>
        mail me </a> about some more tortoise info!
      </p>
      <p><address> &copy; Jan Jansa </address></p>
      <script src='scripts/main.js'></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Note that for css, the path of the image needs to be relative to the css file, not to the base html.  Hence, if your html is in the root, css is in /css and image is in /images, then the property in css would need to be `background-image: url(../images/image.jpg)`

Comment: Jesus, thank you Aleks G, I knew it has to be something little.
It works now.

Comment: Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I'm posting my comment as an answer, as it solved the OP's issue.

For css, the path of the image needs to be relative to the css file, not to the base html. Hence, if your html is in the root (`/`), css is in `/css` and image is in `/images`, then the property in css would need to be

```
background-image: url(../images/image.jpg)
```